# Copy figure in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am asking for a solution to the blurred image I get when I use copy figure option in Matlab. For example, when I plot 3d figure in matlab I get the following image (It is the result of printscreen!)..
[image]

However, when I use the option copy figure I get a blurred image as the following image 
[image].

How can I avoid this as I need to get high resolution image using copy figure option. Thank you in advance for any help you may lend.

Comment: What program are you pasting the figure into?

Comment: I am pasting it to the Microsoft word ..

Comment: I woudl recommend saving as an actual image rather than copying as copying copies the graphics primitives

Comment: I have tried this one. But, the image was not clear. I can't really see the grid lines .

Answer (score 2):

By default, the figure is copied as an Enhanced Metafile (a color graphics format) which works for basic plots such as bar plots, line plots, and other 2D plots but may yield undesirable results for more complex plots as in your case. This is because the rendering of the Metafile content is controlled my Microsoft Word and it may render things differently than MATLAB.

If you need a high resolution image, I would recommend using the `print` command where you can specify the desired resolution (using the `-r` option). Then you can import the resulting image into Word

```
print(gcf, 'myfile.png', '-dpng', '-r300')
```

Alternately, you can use [`export_fig`](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-export-fig) from the File Exchange which better preserves the appearance

Another option would be to change the format used by Copy Figure to tell it to use a bitmap instead

[image]

Or you can call Copy Figure programmatically and specify a different [format](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/print.html#inputarg_clipboardformat) (either a bitmap or PDF)

```
print(gcf, '-clipboard', '-dpdf')
```

Comment: Thank you .. I will try to follow up .